# How to access Informix DB using Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: jdbc, informix, oracle-sqldeveloper

I currently work with Oracle databases, but in a few weeks I need to start learning Informix.
Are there any tools available for Informix, similar to Oracle SQL Developer or any
extensions for connecting SQL Developer to Informix?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get ServerStudio, the core edition is free of charge. You get all the advanced features with your 30 day trial.

http://www.serverstudio.com/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

Oracle SQL Developer can work only with Oracle and MS Access databases. I haven't tried Access but there is tab with "Access" title.

For Informix there is console based application named `dbaccess` and web based application named `ISA - Informix Server Administrator` (as in name this is more for administrators). I use both of them and home made ODBC based application. Some people use other general ODBC/JDBC based tools, for example [quantum](http://quantum.sourceforge.net/) Eclipse plugin.

Comment: thank you for your reply, it was very useful. Also I found the other Eclipse plugin - [Eclipse SQL Explorer](http://www.sqlexplorer.org/) that can work with Informix DB.